# "PUT" request isn't processed

Tags: java, jquery, spring, http, put

I have a jquery script that sends data to my spring controller using `PUT` type. But controller never gets hit. **If i change `PUT` to `POST` everything works as expected**, but i need to use exactly `PUT`. Could you please review my code and tell me what i am doing wrong?

jQuery

```js
var values = $("form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "/user/" + elogin.val(),
                    async: false,
                    data: values,
                    success: function(resp) {\\doStuff}
                 })
```

Controller

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userLogin}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean updateUser(@PathVariable String userLogin,
                              @RequestParam("epassword") String password,
                              ...)
            throws ParseException {
        if (...) {
            return false;
        }
        \\doStuff
        return true;
    }
}
```

FireBug error message

```
400 Bad Request
Response Headers
Connection  close
Content-Length  1072
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 03 Sep 2013 10:21:28 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1

Request Headers
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  168
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  JSESSIONID=5A510B1FB82DA6F3DD9E9FA8D67A8295
Host    localhost:8085
Referer http://localhost:8085/welcome
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Error

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'epassword' is not present
type Status report
message Required String parameter 'epassword' is not present
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Comment: What response do you see in your browser develover tool's "Net" panel? What's your web server software?

Comment: I use tomcat as webserver and firebug. How do i check the response?

Comment: Open Firebug, click on "Net", optionally filter by "XHR". Then trigger the AJAX request. When the request shows up in the Net panel, click to expand it. You're interested in status code and possible error messages sent within the response.

Comment: Yes, updated post for error.

Comment: I figured out, that my request is not sent in json. Will try to convert data into json.

Comment: Actually it is being send as JSON whereas it was expected to be a normal request (with a parameter). Instead of `@RequestParam` use `@ResponseBody` and create an object which can hold the value for you. For this to work properly it might be needed that you configure the [HttpPutFormContentFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HttpPutFormContentFilter.html). (Which might also get it to work with your current situation).

Comment: Thanks. `HttpPutFormContentFilter` worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding to `web.xml`

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I dont know am correct or not but I think we cannot use PUT for jquery ajax

type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

check this 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/